Ubuntu 24.04 unreliable desktop rendering in qemu
I am testing Ubuntu 24.04 on my laptop running Ubuntu 24.04. I'm using Qemu 8.2.2 from the repo, controlled by quickemu (which is mostly 'just' a shell script around Qemu).
Qemu version
qemu-system-x86_64 --version
QEMU emulator version 8.2.2 (Debian 1:8.2.2+ds-0ubuntu1)
Copyright (c) 2003-2023 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers

Quickemu version
quickemu --version
4.9.4

Host machine
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

Host is a ThinkPad Z13 with AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 6860Z - AMD Radeon 680M (rev 14).
Issue description
Sometimes (I can't tell how often, but 'sometimes') booting the Ubuntu 24.04 ISO in Qemu results in a black screen after the plymouth boot logo and animation.

Most of the time it works fine, and I see the desktop installer window on Ubuntu GNOME desktop
Sometimes (1 in 5 or 1 in 10) I do not
The desktop is running - I hear the chimes when the Ubuntu installer window appears
Sometimes switching to VT1 and back to VT2 "fixes" it
Sometimes when it recovers, only some of the screen is painted, thus:


(in this case (which is rare) it is possible to operate the screen, and complete the installation)
What should happen
Booting the same ISO on the same host, with the same virtual machine configuration should reliably start in the same way every single time.
Steps to reproduce

Download and install quickemu as per the instructions - I use the PPA but you don't have to.
Obtain the ISO

quickget ubuntu 24.04

Launch the image

quickemu --vm ubuntu-24.04.conf
Do this many times until it fails.
Summary
Why does the same Ubuntu 24.04 live ISO boot correctly sometimes, and sometimes not?
I have run the same test in Kubuntu and with Ubuntu MATE, and they don't exhibit the black screen.
This feels like a mutter issue, a race condition, or some other virtual GPU, OpenGL support in Qemu, or timing related issue. But I can't fathom what.
I do not wish to use GNOME Boxes, libvirt, nor VirtualBox, or any other platform, I'd like to debug an issue running Ubuntu 24.04 in Qemu as described.

Maybe contact whom ever supports Qemu and ask them if it works with Ubuntu 24.04

I am not convinced this is a Qemu issue. It only happens with Ubuntu 24.04 and 24.10 (daily live). It does not happen with (for example) Kubuntu.

Gnome uses Wayland and Mutter, looks like "mutter" is the culprit
